# reading a large dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am not quite sure about how file-queue works. I am trying to use a large dataset like imagenet as input. So preloading data is not the case, so I am wondering how to use the file-queue. According to the tutorial, we can convert data to TFRecords file as input. Now we have a single big TFRecords file. So when we specify a FIFO queue for the reader, does it mean the program would fetch a batch of data each time and feed the graph instead of loading the whole file of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of pre-fetching depends on your queue capacity. If you use `string_input_producer` for your filenames and `batch` for batching, you will have 2 queues - filename queue, and prefetching queue created by batch. Queue created by `batch` has default capacity of `32`, controlled by `batch(...,capacity=)` argument, therefore it can prefetch up to `32` images. If you follow outline in TensorFlow official howto's, processing examples (everything after `batch`) will happen in main Python thread, whereas filling up the queue will happen in threads created/started by `batch/start_queue_runners`, so prefetching new data and running prefetched data through the network will occur concurrently, blocking when the queue gets full or empty.

Comment: So all the "read", "parsing" and "preprocessing" steps are just defined as a pipeline, right? Only when the real data come in and fill the queue will the real actions happen. Is it the mechanism?

Comment: Yes. It's a pipeline, so stuff that needs output of `batch` will block until another thread enqueues enough things onto this queue

Comment: alright, it is very helpful. Really appreciate your help man.